# Problem with status code of BadRequest .Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

I'm working on an API with .Net Core 2.1 Framework and I faced a pretty strange problem.
In my controller when I catch some specific exceptions I return either a BadRequest or NotFound in which I pass the error message as a parameter.

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ApiViewModel>> DoStuffAsync([FromBody] ApiCommand command)
    {

        if (command == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {
            // some code
            return Ok(ApiViewModel);
        }

        catch (InvalidStuffException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, LogErrorMethodMessage);

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, LogErrorMessage);

            return NotFound(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The thing is even though BadRequest should be returning my error message with a status code of 400 it actually returns 201. Same thing for NotFound. 
I have no idea why this's happening,and I also would like to add the fact that when I return BadRequest without passing any parameter to it the status code returned is the correct one => 400.

When i catch the exception and do the following:

```
             catch (InvalidStuffException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, LogErrorMethodMessage);

                return BadRequest();
            }
```

Here's what i get as a result : Empty message with status code 400

[image]

But if i passed a message in the BadRequest like the following:

```
         catch (InvalidStuffException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, LogErrorMethodMessage);

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
```

I get ma message but with status code 201:

[image]

Can anybody please explain to me the reason behind this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you using the correct action, are you using the correct verb? Get, Post, etc? Maybe there's a filter that overrides the result?

Comment: I just edited my question and I added the full Action Method, and no I don't think there's a filter that overrides the results.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and verify if the method gets called and returns a `BadRequest`?

Comment: Yes I did, the method does get called and the error message is what I get as a result.

Comment: Mayce you should check the syntaxe , cause if i'm not wrong 201 error is kinda related to that , otherwise can you show us what the 201 error says ?

Comment: Hi @ZIADIA Oussama, when I catch the exception I pass the message in the input parameter of BadRequest. This usually returns a status code of 400 with the specified message, I worked with it many times before and never had this problem. But for some reason now it's giving me 201.

I upaded my question to provide what you asked for.

Comment: @SiMohamed Look at the `raw` response from the server.  I expect that `BadRequest` includes the `400` status code, but when you supply the custom values it does not.

Comment: I did check the raw response and it doesn't contain 400, only 201:

```HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbW9oYW1lZC5oYWRyYWNoXHNvdXJjZVxyZXBvc1xyZXR1cm4tYWdyZWVtZW50LWVuZ2luZVxzcmNcQXBpXGFwaVx0eXBlcw==?=
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 10:56:08 GMT
"We can not find any type for the given motif Id"
```
And i did use BadRequest the same way many times but never had this problem. So I really can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Fail to reproduce the issue , could you share a complete simple demo , as the above code exists some customized objects and classes like `InvalidStuffException` and LogMessage ?